# Record not getting saved with lookup field, but does when the field is blank

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lookup

I am new with Lightning and Javascript.
I am trying to learn component level events in Lightning.

I have made a custom object `Pincode__c` child of Account object(Lookup). `Name` and `Account__c` being the fields on `Pincode__c` object.

My aim is to create `Pincode__c` record using a lightning component. Surprising to me, I am only able to save the record if `Account__c` is left blank.

**CreatePINCode.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="CreatePINCode" 
            access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="pincode" type="Pincode__c" default="{
                                                          'sobjectType':'Pincode__c',
                                                          'Name':''
                                                          }" />
<aura:attribute name="pinId" type="String" default="" />

<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordViewForm" objectApiName="Pincode__c">
    <div class="slds-grid"> 
        <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-2 slds-form-element slds-form-element__control"> 
            <lightning:inputField value="{!v.pincode.Name}" fieldName="Name"/>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-1 slds-medium-size--1-of-2 slds-form-element slds-form-element__control"> 
            <lightning:inputField value="{!v.pincode.Account__c}" fieldName="Account__c"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>

<div class="col-md-4 text-center">
    <ui:button class="btn btn-default slds-button_middle" press="{!c.create}">Save Record</ui:button>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

**CreatePINCodeController.js**

```
({
    create : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('Getting Attribute from Cmp');
    var pincode = component.get("v.pincode");

    console.log('Validating Record');
    if($A.util.isEmpty(pincode.Name) || $A.util.isUndefined(pincode.Name)){
        alert('Pincode is Required');
        console.log('Pincode is Required');
        return;
    }

    var action = component.get("c.insertPincode");
    action.setParams({
        pin : pincode
    });

    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('State : '+state);
        if(state == "SUCCESS"){
            var newPincode = {'sobjectType': 'Pincode__c'};
            component.set("v.pincode",newPincode);
            alert('Record is Created Successfully');
            console.log('Record is Created Successfully');
            console.log('Response Return Val'+response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else if(state == "ERROR"){
            var errors = response.getError();
            if(errors){
                if(errors[0] && errors[0].message){
                    console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

**CreatePINCode.apxc**

```
public class CreatePINCode {
@AuraEnabled
public static String insertPincode (Pincode__c pin){
    try{
        if(pin != null){
            insert pin;
        }
    } catch(Exception ex){
        System.debug('Exception Type : '+ex.getTypeName());
        System.debug('Exception Message : '+ex.getMessage());
    }
    return String.valueOf(pin.Id);
}
}
```

**Screenshot of Console Log**
[image: Console Log Screenshot here]

On the first click, it does say the record is saved successfully but it is not visible in the Org

I've been trying to debug this but unable to do so until now.

Comment: Do you see errors if you enter an account and try to save? Do you have a console.log to print the account in the JS, what do you see there? Also does Account has right FLS here? Additionally, you don't need to create a custom apex method for what you are trying to do here unless you want to learn. You can just utilize the standard `submit` here to create the records.

Comment: I don't see any errors while trying to save. FLS shouldn't be a problem here, could you guide where I should look just to be sure?
I can use the standard `submit`, but I have an aim to invoke this custom `create` function on an application level event later.

Comment: Try using `JSON.stringify(pincode)` and see if you get the Account's value or not.

Comment: That returned `{"sobjectType":"Pincode__c","Name":"1432145345432","Account__c":["0017F00001p52KCQAY"]}`.